# RDP through VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I can use RDP internally on the network to servers(2012 R2) and workstations (win10), but when I connect externally through VPN (pptp) I can only reach the RAS server not other servers or workstations (win10).

Comment: after you have VPN'd, are you attempting to connect via hostnames or FQDNs, or IPs? DNS and name resolution issues are common when VPNing into another LAN.

Comment: I have tried both FQDN and IP´s. we recently decommissioned a windows 2008 R2 server as the Primary DC, and after the switch these issues have come.

Comment: Follow up info, I can only ping the RAS server but none of the other IP´s on the internal network.

Comment: Is your clients IP within the same sub net?

Comment: Did you give the vpn user network access for remote access? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687676(v=ws.10).aspx#bkmk_4

Comment: Yes, everything works internally (remote desktop, ping etc) but as soon as I establish the connection via VPN, I can only remote the RAS and none of the internal devicses

Answer (score 1):

After several weeks and failed trials, I decided to go into full troubleshoot mode; after analyzing the traffic and the various logs, I finally managed to resolve the issue without the help of MS.

Besides following the usual guidelines for setting up a VPN, there is a small detail mostly left out in these guides:

- When you're using a VPN connection to create a remote desktop connection to your work PC, the RRAS [Routing and Remote Access Server] will assign you a unique port number, and hat port number is between `49152`and `65535`. 
   So in order for the remote desktop connection to work, you need to add that port range, along with port `3389`, to your firewall allow list.

Here is how it works, with the port numbers:

```
Home PC -> 3389 -> VPN -> 3389 -> Company Router -> 3389 -> RRAS -> 49152-65535 -> Work PC
```